# Delete/modify SharePoint calendar event and sync changes with outlook calendar using MS GraphAPI

Tags: sharepoint

I have a SharePoint application which uses SharePoint calendar to setup meetings, If i delete or modify meetings in SharePoint calendar it should be replicated in outlook calendar as well using GraphAPI.
Can anyone help me with this?

We were using senderWS earlier but now switching to GraphAPI